# Is there any way to find who created an OLAP schema?

Tags: ssas, olap

Is there any way to find out the creator or owner of an OLAP schema in SSAS?

Answer (score 0):

You could of course setup some sort of monitoring service which would log trace events from SSAS and keep track of who's creating databases. But I imagine you mean whether the username who created each database is stored somewhere without you monitoring and logging it yourself. As far as I know, SSAS doesn't store this info.